# When did I receive an LTS point-version upgrade?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, lts, update-history

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and I want to find out when exactly I upgraded to 16.04.2 from 16.04.1. Where can I find this?

If possible/related, where can I see the packages (with their versions) that were affected? (I am mainly interested in GCC)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`16.04.2` is not another distribution compared to `16.04.1`.

`16.04.2` is a new ISO image that included all package upgrades that were released after the 16.04.1 ISO was made.

If you installed regular upgrades, you got all those packages upgraded. That did not happen at one date.

Finally the `base-files` package has been upgraded, where the `/etc/lsb-release` file was updated with `16.04.2`. This date will not tell you anything significant.

Regarding `gcc` I can tell that initially it was `5.3.1-1ubuntu1` in `16.04` (without point). Now you should have the `5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4`.

Comment: Thank you! Where did you find the gcc versions applied in Ubuntu?

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc